# Template function taking iterators as arguments

Tags: c++

Exercise: Write a function template that takes a pair of values that
          represent iterators of unknow type. Find the value that
          occurs most frequently in the sequence

My work:

```
template <typename Iterator> 
typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type
funkcija(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
{

typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type Frequency;
typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type frequencyTemp;
typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type frequencyHighest = 0;


for ( Iterator tempIter = begin; tempIter != end; ++tempIter)
{

    frequencyTemp = count (begin, end, *tempIter);
        if (frequencyTemp > frequencyHighest)
        {
            frequencyHighest = frequencyTemp;
            Frequency = *tempIter;
        }
}

return Frequency;
}

int main()
{
std::vector<std::string> words;

words.push_back("ada");
words.push_back("dada");
words.push_back("mada");
words.push_back("ada");
words.push_back("dada");
words.push_back("ada");
words.push_back("kada");

std::vector<std::string>::iterator first = words.begin();
std::vector<std::string>::iterator last = words.end();

std::cout << "Most frequent value is " << funkcija(first,
    last) << std::endl;

return 0;
}
```

It compiles fine, but when try to run it I got error message that

Debug Assertion Failed!

Expression: invalid null pointer.

I would appreciate if someone could tell me what I did wrong.

Comment: show us how you call the function.

Comment: Sorry about omiting that, I added main() to code example.

Comment: You should learn to use a debugger, so you know exactly where and why it crashes.

Answer (score 3):

Check the types of your variables: some of them are wrong.

The specific thing that's triggering the message is that you are trying to initialize the *string* `frequencyHighest` with a null pointer, as specified by the literal `0`. (i.e. it's trying to use the constructor that takes a C-style string and copies it into the newly constructed `std::string`)

---

When your program is crashing and you don't know what's causing it, one easy thing you can often do is simply keep removing parts of your program until it stops crashing; then you know the crash is probably related to the parts you just removed.

You can usually pin the cause down very narrowly this way -- and even if you can't, it gives you a much better sample program to post when you're asking for help.

Although as the comments said, a debugger would have made it even more plain.

Comment: Thanks, it seems so simple now, and I seem even simpler.

Comment: On the other hand, when I want to call function with iterators for container with ints or doubles, compiler complaint about 'frequencyHighest' being unitialized. Is there a way to make this function works for all types of data?

Comment: @Bane: That brings up another bug; you need to figure out what your function should do when the range is empty (i.e. if `begin == end`). The problem you mention will probably be solved in the process of resolving this bug. It might be worth looking at the design of functions with similar concerns; e.g. `accumulate` from the the standard library.

Comment: @Hurkyl: OK, I added another typename to template defintion (init), added condition in function definition which initialize 'frequencyHighest' to the value of init if init is zero or range is zero, and it all works fine now. Thank you very much for your time and patience.